# How microprocessor keeps track of heap?

Tags: memory-management, language-agnostic, heap-memory, stack-memory

What i know is microprocessors may have a register which can keep track of stack pointer and return address at the time of function call. But what about heap? who keep track of heap pointer? Does memory allocation in heap is really in random order?

Answer (score 2):

The processor *doesn't*. "Heap" and dynamic allocation is on the lowest level part of the operating system, which simply sets aside a part of the (possibly virtual) memory map to be used for dynamic allocations.

On a higher level the runtime support libraries for the programs asks the operating system for memory, usually in the form of "pages" that the operating system then maps to the process asking for it, and then the runtime support library divides up the pages to give out when the process want memory.

<sub>[Note: The above explanation is simplified, for more detailed explanation use your favorite search engine to find specifics.]</sub>